# could not configure a c compiler

Tags: c, linux, node.js, gcc, rtbkit

I am trying to compile some libraries using *gcc 4.7* (which i just upgraded from 4.6.3, somehow it complain about c compiler:

```
/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node/wscript:263: error: could not configure a c compiler!
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'
Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first)
make[1]: *** [program] Error 1
make[1]: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'
Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first)
make[1]: *** [program] Error 1
make[1]: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'
Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first)
make[1]: *** [program] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'

installing
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'
Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first)
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node'
cp: target `/home/rtbkit/local/include/node' is not a directory
make: *** [install_node] Error 1
```

Comment: did you run `waf configure` ?

Comment: C++ tag removed. No information in the question points to C++

Comment: Do I add to download it? where do I run war configure?

Comment: Try adding the node location to the rtbkit user's PATH. /home/rtbkit/platform-deps/node/

Answer (score 1):

gcc-4.7 may not be set as the auto default.  Depending on your OS version you may need to get the 4.7 version from another archive like PPA. This is for Ubuntu:

Install the python tools for adding an archive to apt-get:

```
root@bidder:~# apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Then add the ppa archive:

```
root@bidder:~# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Make sure there are no existing linking:

```
root@bidder:~# update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
root@bidder:~# update-alternatives --remove-all g++
```

Update list of packages from all archives:

```
root@bidder:~# apt-get update
```

Install the 4.7 versions of gcc and g++ :

```
root@bidder:~# apt-get install gcc-4.7
root@bidder:~# apt-get -f install
root@bidder:~# apt-get install g++-4.7
```

Add default links to the new versions:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 20
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7 20
root@bidder:~# update-alternatives --config gcc
root@bidder:~# update-alternatives --config g++
```

Confirm the versions and defaults:

```
root@bidder:~# apt-cache policy gcc
```

Mostly referenced from https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version/26518#26518 and personal experience on Ubuntu 12.04.