# Could not configure a C compiler (Windows)

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, waf

On a Windows system, currently I'm trying a `waf configure` on a directory of code, and it spits out the error "could not configure a C compiler."

Now, I'm 100% certain that I have gcc and g++ installed and in my path because when I type gcc --version, it gives me the current version information. (I'm using mingw and the gcc/g++ are in the /bin subdirectory).

In the author's code directory there is a wscript file which looks like

C_COMPILER = 'gcc-4.7'

CPLUSPLUS_COMPILER = 'g++-4.7'

Now, I have tried changing the strings to simply `gcc` as well as `gcc-4.8.1` (since my current version is 4.8.1), but it still says could not configure compiler.

I tried reading one solution on this same site that looks related, but the solution was on ubuntu and trying to work through those commands didn't help

[could not configure a c compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759038/could-not-configure-a-c-compiler)

I'm at the end of my common sense here after making sure I have gcc and g++ installed, trying different strings in the wscript file trying to get it to recognize I have them installed, and could use some help, thanks.

Edit: I've now tried simply deleting the lines in the wscript file where it changes the compiler name, and suddenly waf configure goes through, but the waf build fails saying things like it can't find really basic things like include vector. The output says it's defaulting to msvs (microsoft visual studio) whereas the author says gcc/g++ is needed; maybe this is the issue but how do I get waf configure/build to use g++/gcc as default?

Comment: can you show the top `wscript` of the project?